# AWS/Cron start schedule specific minute start every 5 minutes

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron

I'm using AWS's Cron validator in EventBridge.  I want to run a schedule starting at 8:55 that runs every 5 minutes until 5 P.M.  Why is AWS telling me this cron schedule runs every hour starting on the 55-minute?

55/5 13-22 ? * MON-FRI *

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `55/5 13-22 ? * MON-FRI *` this means start at 55-minute then continue with 5 min until 59. That means it will run once in a hour.

`*/5 14-21 ? * MON-FRI` you can use this with `55 13 ? * MON-FRI` to handle 8:55.